# Reference programmatically added textboxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

New to visual basic so bear with me,please. Done my project in android,tried it in java,didn't like the fact that a lot of things from android are missing and decided today to try VB.

So,i'm creating some textboxes and labels programmatically,they can be 3,they can be 100,depending on the user.

What i want to do is this :
multiply the value inside the first textbox with the one from the second and display it in the label that i also create programmatically.This should be easy,in java its very easy but in visual basic it appears i can't reference things by the name/tag/id i set to them.

I want to create a Sub that when it is called will calculate everything but i can't figure out how to reference the textboxes.

Could you please help me with that ?

So,here's how i add them programmatically when the user presses a button :

```
Public Sub add()    

 myTxt2.Size = New Drawing.Size(40, 20)
    myTxt2.Name = "cant" & i
    myTxt.Tag = "cant" & i
    myTxt2.Location = New Point(140, 45 + 25 * (rand - 1))
    myTxt2.Text = myTxt2.Name
    myTxt2.Visible = True
    TabPage1.Controls.Add(myTxt2)




    myTxt3.Size = New Drawing.Size(40, 20)
    myTxt3.Name = "pret" & i
    myTxt.Tag = "pret" & i
    myTxt3.Location = New Point(190, 45 + 25 * (rand - 1))
    myTxt3.Text = myTxt3.Name
    myTxt3.Visible = True
    TabPage1.Controls.Add(myTxt3)



    ttotal.Text = "Total: "
    ttotal.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ttotal.Name = "total" & i
    ttotal.Tag = "total" & i
    ttotal.Location = New Point(240, 45 + 25 * (rand - 1))
    ttotal.Size = New Drawing.Size(50, 20)
    ttotal.Visible = True
    ttotal.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    TabPage1.Controls.Add(ttotal)

  Me.Refresh()
    i = i + 1
    rand = rand + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where you are creating these controls.  They look like they already exist and you are just changing the name and the location.

Comment: TabPage1.Controls.Add(myTxt2)  TabPage1.Controls.Add(myTxt3)    TabPage1.Controls.Add(ttotal)

Comment: No, those are existing controls. I don't see the word `new` anywhere,  as in `Dim newBox As New TextBox`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you want. The code creates 2 text boxes and a label. The textboxes are filled with random numbers and the label contains the product. The code creates a set of 2 textboxes and a lablel in a row and the number of rows can be specified. There are more efficient ways to add controls (as suggested by other solutions) however, I wanted to show you here one way of adding controls dynamically to a form.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim max As Integer = 6

        Dim X As Integer = 74
        Dim Y As Integer = 103
        Dim deltaX As Integer = 177
        Dim deltaY As Integer = 50
        Dim tbx1 As New TextBox()

        Dim tbxList As New List(Of TextBox)()
        Dim lblList As New List(Of Label)()

        Dim r As New Random()
        Dim randMax As Integer = 100

        Dim tabIndx As Integer = 0
        'index to control the tabl order of controls.
        Dim j As Integer = -1
        Dim t As Integer = -1
        For row As Integer = 0 To max - 1
            tbxList.Add(New TextBox())
            j = tbxList.Count() - 1

            '
            ' Left TextBox
            ' 
            tbxList(j).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(X, Y)
            tbxList(j).Name = "tbx:" + row.ToString()
            tbxList(j).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 20)
            tbxList(j).TabIndex = tabIndx
            tbxList(j).Text = r.[Next](1, randMax).ToString()
            tabIndx += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(tbxList(j))

            ' 
            ' Right TextBox
            ' 
            tbxList.Add(New TextBox())
            j = tbxList.Count() - 1

            tbxList(j).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(X + deltaX, Y)
            tbxList(j).Name = "tbx:" + row.ToString()
            tbxList(j).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 20)
            tbxList(j).TabIndex = tabIndx
            tbxList(j).Text = r.[Next](1, randMax).ToString()
            tabIndx += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(tbxList(j))

            ' 
            ' label1
            ' 
            lblList.Add(New Label())
            t = lblList.Count() - 1

            lblList(t).AutoSize = True
            lblList(t).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(X + 2 * deltaX, Y)
            lblList(t).Name = "label" + row.ToString()
            lblList(t).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 13)
            lblList(t).Text = row.ToString()
            lblList(t).TabIndex = tabIndx
            lblList(t).Text = "Product: " + (Convert.ToInt32(tbxList(j).Text) * Convert.ToInt32(tbxList(j - 1).Text)).ToString()
            tabIndx += 1
            Me.Controls.Add(lblList(t))

            Y = Y + deltaY
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> it appears i can't reference things by the name/tag/id i set to them.

This is wrong. you can reference them by name.  The `Controls` collection accepts the name as the index, `Me.Controls("TextBox1")`.  The caveat to this is that this returns a control.  To have it typed to a specific type of control you can use the DirectCast method.

To your larger problem.  If you're going to be a adding sets of controls, a panel would work well.  Design the panel with all the controls and add a new one every time you need more